# Getting AccessViolationException when passing a fixed length string from C# to a dll

Tags: c#, excel, dllimport, stringbuilder, access-violation

I have the following (VB6?) code working perfectly in VBA for Excel.  The dll that I am using (x.dll) is a "black box" to me.  I don't know what it is written in, whether it is unmanaged or not.  I know very little about it from an historical technical point of view.  I only know that this particular function works when called from Excel VBA and I cannot similarly get it to function when I call it from C# and I think I should be able to.  Again the value of c.b128 is used by and changed by the dll.

```
'In VBA for excel the value inside "c.b128" is changed from
'" 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789                                                 "
'to
'" 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 123456789                                          "
```

---

### VBA for Excel Code

```
Private Type k128
    b128 As String * 128
End Type

Private Declare Function dllSpace Lib "x.dll" (aInfo As Long, _
   bVec As Long, cQry As k128, dErr As k128) As Long    

Function Space() As Long

    Dim c  As k128
    Dim d  As k128

    c.b128 = Left(" 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789", 128)
    d.b128 = Left("", 128)


    Space = dllSpace(-1, -1, c, d)

 End Function
```

---

I tried to implement the same in .NET and got an error when it gets to "return dllSpace(-1, -1, c, d);"
An unhandled exception of type system.accessviolationexception occured in [...] attempted to read or write protected memory.  other memory is corrupt

I need to convert this to .NET and I get an AccessViolationException.  Everywhere I read that the memory reserved by StringBuilders are accessible to dlls in C#.  I have tried “ref StringBuilder” I have tried using byte[], I have tried using the unsafe descriptor, I don’t understand.  Also if there is a way for me to see more of what is going on in memory using the IDE that would also be helpful to me.  I can see all my variables in the local and watch windows, but I can’t see and don’t know how to see more details about the exception that is thrown.  I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop on a Win7 32 bit OS machine.

This is a snippet from my c# code

---

### C# Code Snippet

```
[DllImport(@"x.dll")]
private static extern int dllSpace(int aInfo,
                  int bVec,
                  StringBuilder cQry,
                  StringBuilder dErr);


public int StartTheDataSpace()
{


    StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder(128);

    StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder(128);

    c.Append(" 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789                                                 ");

    return dllSpace(-1, -1, c, d);
}
```

---

Comment: Try catching the Win32Exception. `catch(Win32Exception w)` then you can call `var e=w.GetBaseException();` to get more detail on exception.

Comment: Thank you for the response @vendettamit, I am having trouble with this.

Comment: Thank you for the response @vendettamit, I am having trouble with this.

Comment: `public int StartTheDataSpace()
{
    //I've not been totally forthcoming here...
    //There was actually an array by which the integers were passed
    
    int[] try1 = {0, -1, -1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder(128);
    StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder(128);

    c.Append(" 12345678901234[...]                          ");

try
{
    return dllSpace(try1[1], try1[1], c, d);
}
catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.Data);
return -1;
}
}`

Comment: The above code is not working for me...  I thought I knew how to implement a try - catch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBA code makes it clear that what you have is actually a structure containing a fixed length string. That means that `StringBuilder` is the wrong type. You should instead use:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct k128
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string b128;
}
```

Also, as I understand it, VBA uses `ByRef` as default. So the C# declaration should be:

```
[DllImport(@"x.dll")]
private static extern int dllSpace(
    ref int aInfo,
    ref int bVec,
    ref k128 cQry,
    ref k128 dErr
);
```

Now, it so happens that `ref k128` has the same memory layout when marshalled as `StringBuilder` with capacity 128 so you may find it more convenient to switch back to:

```
[DllImport(@"x.dll")]
private static extern int dllSpace(
    ref int aInfo,
    ref int bVec,
    StringBuilder cQry,
    StringBuilder dErr
);
```

Comment: And here I was thinking that I tried every combination.  Thank you David Heffernan, I am embarrassed to say I have been working on this particular problem for many days.  I simply added ref in front of the two integer declarations and the dllSpace returned 0 which is the "no error" response.  Thanks again.